# ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: " " by copying .txt file to postgres table

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to copy txt file to postgres database but I'm getting an error as follows:

```
[22P02] ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: " "
Where: COPY eurotax_consumer, line 1, column tcomanmi: " "
```

But I'm using `WITH NULL AS ''` as the docs says:

```
COPY eurotax_consumer FROM 'path/to/file.txt' WITH NULL AS '';
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the value in the input file is not an empty string but a string with a single space (blank) in it.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to enter a string into an INT column. Can you set the destination column to a string type the do explicit conversion after insertion ?

Comment: Yes, because that record is empty. But `WITH NULL AS ''` should replace the string with NULL.